# How to make strace keep following children after the death of the father/mother:))?

Tags: process, monitoring, strace, thread

I use this command to trace all the things that are done or started from a shell.

```
sudo strace -e trace=memory -o outm -ff -p <the pid of the terminal instance I want to trace> -f
```

But the problem is When I for example start firefox or chromium, I get so many messages like:

```
strace: Process 16776 attached
strace: Process 17508 attached
strace: Process 17509 attached
strace: Process 17512 attached
```

But then if open a new tab etc no new processes are created. My guess is that these applications create so many different processes and then kill the parent so `strace` stops tracing the children. So, how can I make `strace` keep following children after their father/mother is killed or terminated?

Also please tell me if my command is not doing what I want.

What I want is to trace all the memory allocations/deallocations of all of the processes and threads of the system. So when I'm sure this function is working fine I want to make a module out of it and put in in the kernel and try to trace the earliest process possible in the system.

Comment: why not instead write it using SystemTap or sysdig if it's going to be in the kernel?

Comment: @thrig I don't know what they are. But I can't install anything on the system. it should be a module that works out of the box.

Comment: how are you going to "make a module out of it[strace?] and put in[sic] in the kernel" if you can't install anything?

Comment: I think I can have the same functionality with ptrace, can't I?

Comment: I guess you could try to write something ptrace something. might be horrifically slow, or a reinvention of SystemTap or sysdig...